# Binding DataGridView to a list of various obects? c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, binding

Let say I'll create a DataGridView with four columns of types TextBox, Button, ComboBox, and Link. How would I populate something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0wfd4yz.aspx
I was surprise that it was difficult to find such example :-/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [DataGridView.Rows property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx).

From MSDN:

> You can use the Rows collection to manually populate a DataGridView control instead of binding it to a data source.